# UINavigationController makes one view modaled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have two pages load at beginning, login page and register page. Register page is behind login page.

On login page there is a button can call out demo page, so I need navigation controller for login page, so that can get "back" button when demo page call out.

So I set navigation controller in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    LoginViewController *_loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];


    RegisterViewController *_registerViewController = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:_registerViewController.view];
    [_registerViewController release];

    [self.window addSubview:_loginViewController.view];


    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_loginViewController];
    [self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];
    [_loginViewController release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This can make button on login page works good, but when move out login page and shows register page, register page cannot response user action.

What's wrong with the code?

---

EDIT:

My bad, didn't say clearly. When I say login page "move out", it does not really move out entirely. There is still one fifth left in screen. Then register page appears. In this case, I add both login page and register page in AppDelegate. Also, I don't use XIB...

@dasblinkenlight and @hiren443？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are adding the views of both controllers to the `window`, and also use the navigation controller incorrectly.

Here is what you should do instead:

- Create the navigation controller first
- Push the registration page, and then the login page onto the controller
- Hide the [back] button for the login page
- Add navigation controller as the only subview of the main window

In the controller of the login page, call navigation controller's `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` to display the registration page.

Answer (score 2):

first add login

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    LoginViewController *_loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_loginViewController];
    [self.window addSubview:self.navController.view];
    [_loginViewController release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

in login page add button and action method

```
-(IBAction)DemoBtnPressed
{
  RegisterViewController *_registerViewController = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:_registerViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it. My way is: when trying move login page up (not move out, 1/5 left in screen) to show register page, not move login page but move login page navigation controller.

But you guys' comment do helped! Thanks anyway!!!